# SelectedValue of DropDownlList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview that has dropdownlist in edit section, I want to bind the selectedvalue from database when editing. In designer section there is no SelectedValue attribute, it gives runtime error. What to do any help?? Is there any way to handle it from code-behind?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLCompany" runat="server" DataValueField="cname" DataTextField="cname" SelectedValue = '<%# Bind("cname") %>'  >
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="CompanyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cname") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>   
             </asp:TemplateField>
```

---

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList DDLCompany = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDLCompany");
            DropDownList DDLPrinter = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DDLPrinter");

            if (DDLCompany != null)
            {
                DDLCompany.DataSource = userobj.FetchCompanyList();
                DDLCompany.DataBind();
                DDLCompany.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();                
            }

            if (DDLPrinter != null)
            {
                DDLPrinter.DataSource = userobj.FetchPrinterList();
                DDLPrinter.DataBind();
                DDLPrinter.SelectedValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your code behind is set up to do it...

Comment: No it does not set. It selects the first data of DDL. It does not binds the actual value from database

Answer (score 1):

- In Codebehind you have to check
  for e.Row.RowType==
  DataControlRowType.DataRow **&&
  e.Row.RowState ==
  DataControlRowState.Edit** in
  RowDataBound before you find your
  Dropdwonlist.
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx
- On aspx you can set the
  seletcedvalue in the following way:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294.aspx